# when i pass date through variables inside query don't get output

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am facing a very strange issue trying to solve it since last 6 hours but all in vain. When i store date inside the variable the query shows 0 results. But when i store date date directly inside query it gives me output. But if i store date inside variable like below it does not give me any output.

```
$fromdate="2020-01-08";
$todate='2020-08-14';
```

And below is a query

```
"SELECT A1.u_id_fk, A3.full_name, A1.created AS check_in_at, A2.created AS check_out_at, TIMEDIFF(A2.created, A1.created) AS total_time 
FROM timesheet 
AS A1 INNER JOIN timesheet AS A2 ON A1.u_id_fk = A2.u_id_fk AND DATE(A1.created) = DATE(A2.created) 
INNER JOIN users A3 on A1.u_id_fk=A3.u_id 
WHERE 1 = 1 AND A1.status = 'Check-In' AND A2.status = 'Check-Out' 
  AND DATE(A1.created) BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate 
  AND DATE(A2.created) BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate 
ORDER BY A1.created DESC"
```

above query only returns rows when i provide date directly inside query such '2020-01-08' instead of :fromdate and :todate.

Comment: Try prepending `EXPLAIN` before`SELECT` to see what gets filtered.

Comment: Please show a _proper_ [mre] of the issue, not just the SQL.